# session checking is not working after uploading to server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

this is my controller for login

```
    public function user_login_process()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required');


if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{

    if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in']))
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/intropage');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/login/login_dashboard');
    }
} 
else
{
    $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username'),'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $result = $this->gt_login_model->login($data);
    if ($result == true)
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $result = $this->gt_login_model->read_user_information($username);
        if ($result != false) 
        {
        $session_data = array('username' => $result[0]->user_name);
        // Add user data in session
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
        $this->load->view('admin/intropage');
        }
    } 
    else
    {
    $data = array('error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password');
    $this->load->view('admin/login/login_dashboard', $data);
    }
}
}
```

this is the code that i used to check whether the session is set or not in other pages

```
if(!$this->session->userdata['logged_in'])
    {

    redirect("gt_login");
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

but this checking doesnot works ie, in other pages

```
$session_data = array('username' => $result[0]->user_name);
```

the value inside this array is not available.This problem is only when i uploaded my project to the server . But when i woked in local host this whole project works fine . 
now the main problem is i cant check wheather the session is set or not in other pages .

Comment: What are you using to upload the file?

Comment: Check your php version !

Comment: sorry i didnt get that.

Comment: Are you uploading with ajax? Or traditional form post?

Comment: uploading here i means that i put the whole project to the live server for working as awebsite.

Comment: Sorry my mistake - I thought you meant you were losing session data after uploading a file.

Comment: Have you set your session save path on the config.php

Comment: sorry i didnt get that can you please tell how it is .

Comment: On line 383 on config.php some thing like `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';`

Comment: `if(!$this->session->userdata['logged_in'])` userdata is function it should be like `if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))` , I don't know how it works in your local environment too.